# How to achieve variable gain using a micro-controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I have a sine signal Vsignal below which is AC coupled and will be buffered by an LT1490 to the line input of a MOSFET power amplifier.

[image]

I'm able to control the frequency of the Vsignal through Arduino. But I also need to control the gain through Arduino.

What approaches is possible for a variable gain? Is there any dedicated IC for such purpose? I need a variable output between 0.25Vrms to 3Vrms for instance. I have no experience on such topic. Input to LT1490 will be fixed 500mV amplitude i.e 1Vpk-pk. In case, how would a digital pot work for the setting the gain?

How about changing Rp with a 10k digital pot as below like a MCP41010? Does anybody have experience with such use?

[image]

Comment: Search keyword - "DAC"

Comment: Digital pot, multiplying DAC, or http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/pga-vga/overview.html

Comment: Because Arduino uses PWM for analog output, if your design is not sensitive you can try on this code, https://github.com/Sir-SpankalotUK/Arduino-Sine-Wave-LED/blob/master/SineLED/SineLED.ino , change this line  "int value = 128 + 128 * sin(something * 1.1 * PI);" to "int value = 128 + Gain * sin(something * 1.1 * PI);" where Gain is 0 to 128

Comment: The output is not directly from Arduino. Read the question.

Comment: What device is producing the signal?  How are you controlling its frequency?

Comment: @ThePhoton Arduino is controlling through a DDS module. The RC is removing the offset and then the sine is buffered. Now through same Arduino I want to control the gain by using MCP4010 in the feed back path. Never tried before.

Comment: Does the DDS have variable amplitude?

Comment: I dont think so. It seems it is fixed. http://telecnatron.com/modules/ad9850/index.html

Comment: I modified this code http://softgeniedoc.dk/contents/projects/AD9850_tonegen/AD9850.html As u see four pins available connected to Arduino

Comment: If your maximum frequency is 20 Hz, why even use a DDS chip? Your Arduino is plenty powerful enough to calculate a sine at more than 40 times a second, and you can then simply multiply a number to it. Done! Saved you a DDS IC, a variable amplifier, and calibration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because like your previous DDS questions it is an XY problem: you are trying to use a fixed function *radio* part for what is not even an audio frequency problem.  Generate the signal in an *appropriate* way and you will not have these problems.  Also worth noting that modern power amplifiers for this frequency range would be some variation of switching mode anyway (ie, class D, etc).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Resolution.

Comment: @user1234 what is that supposed to mean, "Resolution"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Arduino will act like a 8-bit DAC, the module has 10-bit DAC I meant but that was not the main issue I don't remember . Having said that I have already tried what you have suggested and were not happy with the results either was the very low freq problem or something else like difficult coding. An example what you suggest here I guess http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/interfaces-advanced/arduino-dds-sinewave-generator/ If I had time I would try more and kind of stuck with using what I have.

Comment: @user1234 the bit depth has virtually no effect on your frequency accuracy at this scale, also I don't see how the "Arduino will act like a 8-bit DAC": That's simply not true; the timer units of most Arduino-compatible ICs are way, way finer than 8 bit. And you're not stuck with using a DDS chip to produce a sine wave: that's your choice, and it's IMHO a bad one; all the problems you're trying to solve are due to you choosing to generate something that's easier to do on a microcontroller with a chip that was meant for a completely different frequency range.

Comment: essentially, you could just as well use a single bit DAC and produce the same frequencies – you'd just then have to filter the harmonics. The difference in harmonics between 8 and 10 bits are 12 dB SNRq, but I doubt this will make any difference to your application, but you really haven't mentioned that. Even if 10 vs 8 bit makes a difference: your arduino could easily oversample that 20 Hz by a factor of say 2048; that's an additional accuracy gain that would lead to far, far more than 10 ENOB.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Basically I already am able to control the freq. That's the reason I insist with this module. The other methods you mention I dont know how to achieve., So that is the main problem I dont know and it will take too much time for me to learn that level of coding. I contrl it through PC and I had issues before with Arduino's . The real problem is the coding part is beyond my skills. Im sue what you suggest makes very sense. But I dont have much time for part of a project,

Comment: But these problems are also way above your skill level. So learn to solve the actual problem, instead of trying to solve problems you only have because you've chosen an approach that only you think will get you far. Fully agree with @ChrisStratton here, this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) par excellence! Ask a new question on this site, where you say "I need a high-power (defined that) output of variable amplitude (define that) of a single tone over a frequency range (define that). My first approach was with a DDS IC, but this only lead to problems (define those). How do I achieve…

Comment: … my final application goal (tell us what you want to achieve overall, not just the small problem you're trying to solve now)?" $$ \\ $$ That would allow us to actually help you find a way that you can go!

Comment: Oh mannn, good night--

Answer (score 2):

> What approaches is possible for a variable gain?

One approach if you are on a budget is to use high frequency PWM to toggle between the audio signal and 0 volts. The resulting waveform can be simply low pass filtered to recover the audio at a reduced volume that is proportional to PWM duty cycle: -

[image]

Picture from [this Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102874/how-to-mirror-resistor-use-same-variable-resistance-for-multiple-op-amp-gains/102875).

So, in the top image the input is (say) a triangle wave. The 2nd image shows the triangle wave and the PWM signal (above nyquist of course) and this samples the triangle wave at reasonable speed. After low pass filtering (can be as simple as an RC filter) the amplitude is reduced. Altering the duty cycle changes the volume level.

You can implement this with a transistor (with care) or an analogue gate.

Comment: nice. Especially considering that OP is anyway using a dedicated DDS chip to generate a 0.1 – 20 Hz sine wave, the numerical approach seems the best.

Comment: Your figure doesn't show PWM.  It shows modulation with a constant pulse width.

Comment: @ScottSeidman the figure is an example at one particular duty cycle acting on an input waveform that happens to be a triangle wave. Are you suggesting that I repeat the diagram from several other examples of duty cycle or maybe you have misinterpreted what I said in the answer?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'm not saying that the PWM creates the original triangle wave signal; I'm saying that using a transistor or an analogue gate the input (triangle wave, sine wave or audio or whatever) can be chopped up and reconstructed with a low pass filter at a lower amplitude where that lower amplitude is dependent on the duty cycle of the PWM.

Comment: Why not *just* use PWM to produce whatever waveform one needs?  What does this buy you beyond that?

Comment: Ahh -- the AC thing.

Comment: I think that deserves to be made into an answer - I was just focussing on the amplitude control part and hadn't read in the comments about the DDS chip. "Ahh -- the AC thing" - I don't think that is a problem if you used PWM to make a 20 Hz sinewave.

Answer (score 1):

Look for digitally controlled variable gain amplifiers. Analog+Linear have quite a [selection](https://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/variable-gain-amplifiers/digital-control-vgas.html) of those. But be aware that a lot of those have a very limited frequency range and both an upper and a lower limit. If your signal is very low in frequency (let's say below 1kHz), then it's easier to build a VGA using discrete components. Use your favorite opamp amplifier structure and use a [digital potentiometer](https://www.analog.com/en/products/digital-to-analog-converters/digital-potentiometers.html) to control the gain. For intermediate frequencies, a fixed amplifier plus a variable attenuator (either [digital step attenuators](https://www.analog.com/en/products/rf-microwave/attenuators/digital-step-attenuators.html) or [PIN diode based Waugh attenuator](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/waugh-attenuator)) would be the lower noise choice.

Comment: My freq range is from 0.1Hz up to 20Hz Im not interested in rest. But the PGA's do not have many gain stages. I thought if I use digital pot in feedback I have 256 different values. What do you think?

Comment: Oh.. this low a frequency.... Ok. Then either use the opamp+digital poti approach or alternatively a multiplying DAC. Digital poties go up to 12bit and multiplying DACs up to 16bit. That ought to be enough for anyone.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was thinking of this and changing Rp with a digital pot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqIdp.png

Comment: I would go for a non-inverting amplifier, as this allows you to ground one side of the digital poti instead of having it completely floating. Even though both work, the one-side-grounded approach makes the circuit more benign.

Comment: But noniverting will not let me to attenuate. My input is 1Vrms but I aklso need sown to 0.25Vrms. Maybe I can lower it at the input though..

Comment: Ground ed approach? Could you draw that topology if possible? Would be great to understand.

Comment: KotH is right, user1234, why wouldn't a noninverting amplifier allow you to attenuate? I'd also agree: a multiplying DAC, possibly fed by an opamp buffer of your signal, would be the most straightforward way; honestly, at < 20 Hz, you could also use the ADC of your microcontroller and its PWM unit to digitize the input, then simply multiply it with a number of your choice, before dividing the result down to your PWM unit's dynamic range. Any microcontroller with an ADC would be able to so massively oversample without breaking any sweat, that jitter and the inefficiencies of the Arduino

Comment: …simply don't matter. In any case, avoid any analog circuitry where you're the one in charge of hand-tuning analog gains – that would require a lot of measurement, and will quickly drift off (hurr durr, a pun) into stability considerations – both in terms of temperature and temporal stability, as well as in terms of system theoretic (BIBO) stability.

Comment: Of course, if your signal is a sine anyway, skip the variable amplification of the DDS; just replace your DDS chip with something that you just calculate within your microcontroller. Saves you ICs and analog headaches.